# Executing a function with paste to create a new variable in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, function

Data:

```
structure(list(`p value` = c(0.00151124736422317, 0.804709799937324, 
0.0192537412780042, 0.000467854188597731, 4.80216666553605e-06, 
0.0231434946595433), significance = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE)), .Names = c("p value", "significance"), row.names = c("Q5.i", 
"Q5.ii", "Q5.iii", "Q5.iv", "Q5.v", "Q5.vi"), class = "data.frame")
```

Objective:
To create a function that would take input of dataframe name and a (new) variabe name.
The function would:

1. create a new variable that is based on the row name of the dataframe
2. delete the row name
3. reorder the variable so that the newly created
   column is first column

Challenges:
I am stuck at the first step.

I've searched the internet and stackoverflow for snippets of code that would help and I've managed to hammer something although it couldn't work.
What have I tried:

```
row2col<-function(df, varname){
 eval(parse(text=paste(df, "[[", "'", varname, "'", "]]", "<-row.names(", df, ")", sep="")))
}


row2col<-function(df, varname){
  assign(parse(text=paste(df, varname, sep="$")), row.names(df))
}
```

Results:

1. nothing happened (not even an error message)
2. a character vector of row names (rather than a variable within the dataframe) was created

Thanks for your help and attention to this post.

Comment: R rule of thumb - if you are ever using `eval` `assign` `parse`.... don't. :-)

Comment: This function exists already, as [`dplyr::add_rownames()`](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr) and [`tibble::rownames_to_column()`](https://github.com/hadley/tibble/)

Comment: @alistaire Thanks for your sharing. I use the dplyr package extensively and didn't even notice its already in there.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use `eval`, `parse`, `assign` - that's in many cases not the right approach. Here's a simple alternative:

```
row2col <- function(dat, varname) {
  dat[[varname]] <- row.names(dat)  
  row.names(dat) <- NULL
  dat[, c(varname, setdiff(names(dat), varname))]
}
```

And then you can test it:

```
> row2col(df, "testcol")
#  testcol      p value significance
#1    Q5.i 1.511247e-03         TRUE
#2   Q5.ii 8.047098e-01        FALSE
#3  Q5.iii 1.925374e-02         TRUE
#4   Q5.iv 4.678542e-04         TRUE
#5    Q5.v 4.802167e-06         TRUE
#6   Q5.vi 2.314349e-02         TRUE
```

Comment: And I struggled for half a day with the first objective only...thanks very very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Create new var using row names.

```
data$new_var <- row.names(data)
```

Reset row names

```
row.names(data) <- NULL
```

Reorder data frame with new var first

```
data <- data[, c(ncol(data):(ncol(data) - 1))]
```