# How to create a new variable based on another variable's value?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a vector containing string representing names of variables that should be in my final df. Those names could change every time based on other conditions.

```
x <- colnames(df)

y <- c("blue", "yellow", "red")

z <- setdiff(y,x)
```

Let's say my result now is that: `z = c("blue", "red")`

I would like a function that, `if` any element of vector y is missing from z, `THEN` the function will create a column on `df` with such element as variable name.

---

Here's my inconclusive attempt:

```
if (length(z) > 0) {
  for (i in z) {
   df$i <- NA
  }
}
```

The part I don't know how to do is pass `i` as an argument for creating a new variable on `df`. 
In my example: I should finally get `df$yellow` as a new variable of `df`.

---

I checked many posts, either I don't understand how it works, or they are not doing what I need, some for reference:

- [Create new variables based on another df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52581568/create-new-variables-based-on-another-df)
- [Rename variable based on textInput value in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51972398/rename-variable-based-on-textinput-value-in-shiny)
- [Executing a function with paste to create a new variable in a dataframe in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38068195/executing-a-function-with-paste-to-create-a-new-variable-in-a-dataframe-in-r)
- [Evaluate expression given as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743698/evaluate-expression-given-as-a-string)

Comment: You can use `[` instead of `$` i.e. `df[z] <- NA`  Reproducible `mtcars[z] <- NA;
 head(mtcars)`

Comment: Thank you @akrun this worked perfectly, I see I'm really missing the basics sometimes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was indeed the simple suggestion from @akrun:

> You can use [ instead of $ i.e. df[z] <- NA Reproducible mtcars[z] <- NA; head(mtcars)

Hence, as follows:

```
 if (length(z) > 0) {
  for (i in z) {
   df[i] <- NA
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is one possibility without any loops:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:5)
z <- c("blue", "red")

df[z] <- NA_character_

  x blue red
1 1   NA  NA
2 2   NA  NA
3 3   NA  NA
4 4   NA  NA
5 5   NA  NA
```